# Run a single command in an interactive powershell using vagrant winrm

Tags: powershell, vagrant, winrm

When running:
`vagrant winrm -s powershell -c "[System.Environment]::UserInteractive"`

The output is `False`, the VM is using Windows Server 2019.

An EXE is written to run as a service only if called from a non-interactive context, and runs as an executable if called from an interactive one - we need the output of the EXE, so how do we run a command such that `[System.Environment]::UserInteractive` is True for the running exe, and the output is received back at the host?

The source code of the app can be similar to this (C#):

```
if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
    ServiceBase.Run (new Service ());
else
    Start (args);
```

Extra:

My host is macOS so I can't run `vagrant powershell`, though that too might have the same issues.
I get this when running the EXE using `vagrant winrm -s powershell -c "MyApp.exe"`:

```
Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger.  A Windows Service must first be installed and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool or the NET START command.
```